# Checklistbox Add and check items newly added items only

Tags: c#

How i can automatically check the newly added items to Checklistbox?
I don't want to check the existing items which is already processed.

Here's my code:

```
    public static void AddItemsToListBox(CheckedListBox lb, string input, Regex pattern)
    {
        lb.BeginUpdate();
        lb.Items.AddRange(pattern.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Where(m => !lb.Items.Cast<string>().Any(item => item
            .Equals(m.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))).Select(m => m.Value).ToArray());
        lb.SelectedIndex = lb.Items.Count - 1;
        lb.EndUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: No issue with the code. I'm just showing maybe the answer to my question can be added to my current code. or can improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to find the matches that does not exists in the Checkedlistbox and add those matches to the list. Your code is fine, but I would do a bit of refactoring for more readability.

```
    public static void AddItemsToListBox(CheckedListBox lb, string input, Regex pattern)
    {
        var newItems = pattern.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
            .Where(m => !lb.Items.Cast<string>().Any(item => item.Equals(m.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToArray();
        if (newItems.Any())
        {
            lb.BeginUpdate();
            foreach (var item in newItems)
            {
                lb.Items.Add(item, true); // adds and checks the item
            }
            lb.SelectedIndex = lb.Items.Count - 1;
            lb.EndUpdate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much. But how I can automatically check the newitems?

Comment: this is the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696061/automatically-auto-check-every-new-item-in-a-checkedboxlist-in-c-sharp but no answer yet

Comment: I have updated the code to check newly added items.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to answer my own question.
But thanks to @G10 for refactoring my code.

here's the solution if anyone else need in the future

```
 public static void AddItemsToListBox(CheckedListBox lb, string input, Regex pattern)
    {
        var newItems = pattern.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
            .Where(m => !lb.Items.Cast<string>().Any(item => item.Equals(m.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .ToArray();
        if (newItems.Any())
        {
            lb.BeginUpdate();
            lb.Items.AddRange(newItems);
            lb.SelectedIndex = lb.Items.Count - 1;
            lb.EndUpdate();
        }

        //Automatically check newly added items only
        for (int i = 0; i < lb.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < newItems.Length; x++)
            {
                if (lb.Items[i].ToString() == newItems[x])
                {
                    lb.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @zacky - I didn't know you need to check the newly added items. In your solution you dont have to loop through to check the newly added items. Please refer to my solution, I have updated the code.

Comment: Wow I'm gonna test it later. Thank you so much